# PHP in Background-image tag

Tags: php, html

On a Wordpress theme site I have this code:

```
<div class="gallery-img" style="background-image: url(<?php echo esc_url($image['sizes']['thumbnail']); ?>);">
```

However I need the background image url to be in ''.

So it works like this:

```
<div class="gallery-img" style="background-image: url('<?php echo esc_url($image['sizes']['thumbnail']); ?>');">
```

With it like that the PHP then does not work, how can I do the above so it works and so it has the '' around it?

Comment: You try to use `echo <div ---` ?

Comment: Both versions should work the same, with what you have shown alone there is no apparent reason why it shouldn’t. But why do you think you _need_ this in the first place? With properly encoded URLs, the quotes should not be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about inverting your single and double quotes ?

```
<div class="gallery-img" style='background-image: url("<?php echo esc_url($image['sizes']['thumbnail']); ?>");'>
```